# jsonp: callback jQuery AJAX with Multiple Array data

Tags: ajax, jquery, callback, jsonp

Here i'm doing a JSONP request, that will get an object literal passed into the callback function.

My Issue:

1.From the filename.php i'm  passing two different array's like :

```
        echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($manufacturers). ');';               
       echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($Stock). ');';
```

2.I'm receiving only one array as output at a time.
3. i need the both array .

```
                   function onLoad(){
                        var output = $('#product');
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'filename.php',
                            data : {type : 'details'},
                            dataType: 'jsonp',
                            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                            timeout: 5000,
                            success:function(data){
                                $.each(data, function(c,prdetail){

                                    if(prdetail.field_name=='' || prdetail.field_name==undefined )
                                    {
                                        var firstdata= '<h2 >'+prdetail.field_name1+ '</h2>';
                                        output.append(firstdata);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var secondata ='<h2 >'+prdetail.field_name2+ '</h2>';
                                        output.append(secondata);
                                    }
});
            }
        });
    }
```

FILENAME.PHP

```
     if($status=1)
      {
            $manufacturers_sql = mysql_query('select * FROM tablename');
    $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $records = array();
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $records[] = $row;

     echo $_GET['jsoncallbacks'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
         }
        else
         { 
            $manufacturers_sql = mysql_query('select * FROM tablename');
    $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $records = array();
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $records[] = $row;

     echo $_GET['jsoncallbacks'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
           }
```

Comment: Thats not gonna work, you should combine the arrays in 1 single object. Because the result on echo'ing both arrays seperatly is that you request a Javascript file with 2 functions (which have the same name)

Comment: is it possible to append the objects, i mean by giving the different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$response = array();

$response['manufacturers'] = $manufacturers;
$response['Stock'] = $Stock;

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($response). ');';
```

Comment: you mean  in the php file to do this

Comment: @NewBorn yeah..why..?? you don't have it.?

Comment: i'm coded like the $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $manufacturers[] = $row; you are asking me to rewrite like $response['manufacturers'] = $manufacturers;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25840/discussion-between-new-born-and-dipesh-parmar)